# Django form: phone field not showing

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a contact form on my Django website.
For now, this is my code:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class Client(models.Model):
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    fullName = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py:

```
def contact(request):
    # return render(request, 'contact.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # send email code goes here
            return HttpResponse('Thanks for contacting us!')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I of course installed `phonenumber_field` and added it in settings.py

This is the result, phone field missing:
[image: form]

Any help is hugely appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a *model* field, whereas for a form, you need a *form field*:

```
from django import forms
#            a form field ↓
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    fullName = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```